# System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]

Tags: c#

I have the following class named Node

```
 class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public Node Parent { get; set; }
        public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Node: " + ParentId + " " + Operator + " " + Id + " " + Children.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I want to get for each `ParentId`  all `children`

> [0 Node: 0 ~ 0 5,4]]
>       [1 Node: 12 + 1 2,3,5,]]
>       [2 Node: 12 + 2 7,5,3,]]
>       and so on

```
 var map = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
 File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\myfile.txt",
      map.Select(x => "[" + x.Key + " " + x.Value + "]").ToArray());
```

But I got

> [0 Node: 0 ~ 0 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [1 Node: 12 + 1 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [2 Node: 12 + 2 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [3 Node: 8 + 3 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [4 Node: 8 + 4 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [5 Node: 8 + 5 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [6 Node: 8 + 6 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [7 Node: 8 + 7 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [8 Node: 2 ~ 8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]
>       [9 Node: 2 ~ 9 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Node]]

Comment: Break the problem down into a smaller problem.  Your problem is not displaying the entire dictionary.  There is one particular operation within that higher level operation that isn't working, and a bunch that *are* working.  Isolate just the one part that *isn't* working.  Restrict the code, and your problem statement, to just the part that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Children.ToString();` with:

```
string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => x.Id));
```

You are calling `ToString` on a `IList<Node>` so it's giving you the type name.If you want to see Ids of the child nodes you can use `string.Join` as shown above.