# Dictionary in C# with list of Int[] values not displaying

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am trying to display the values from a dictionary function but it does not display the value, what it shows is below -

```
1007 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32[]] 

1006 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32[]] 

1009 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32[]] 

1008 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32[]]
```

the code I am using is shown below

```
    clsCollaborativeFilter mri = new clsCollaborativeFilter();
    Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> movRecommendations = mri.aList1();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int[]>> kvp in movRecommendations)
    {
        da.Text += kvp.Key;
        da.Text += " ";
        da.Text += kvp.Value;
        da.Text += "<br/>";
    }
    return da.Text;
```

I cant seem to understand why this is happening

Comment: Well, you're calling `ToString()` on a `List<int[]>`. How were you *expecting* that to perform a conversion, and why? (I'd strongly recommend building all the text in a StringBuilder first, and then setting da.Text at the end, btw.)

Comment: Related: [Question regarding C#'s `List<>.ToString`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050507/question-regarding-cs-list-tostring), but I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of something out there.

Comment: [C# System.Collections.Generic.List`1System.String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106181/c-sharp-system-collections-generic-list1system-string)

Comment: [System.Collections.Generic.List`1test.Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069734/system-collections-generic-list1test-node)

Comment: [System.Collections.Generic.List`1System.String issue in mvc4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713262/system-collections-generic-list1system-string-issue-in-mvc4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding a `List` of an `Array` of `ints` to a string, in the line: `da.Text += kvp.Value;` so what it is doing, is it is adding the *signature* of the `List` of `Array`s because it doesn't know exactly what you are trying to do.

What you can do instead is:

```
da.Text += String.Join(", ", kvp.Value.SelectMany(i => i));
```

Comment: yea that seem to work now I am able to see the values I required so thanks

Answer (score 1):

...or assuming that it really is a dictionary-of-list-of-int-arrays, then:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(Int32 key in movRecommendations.Key) {
    List<Int32[]> listOfArrays = movRecommendations[ key ];

    sb.Append( key );
    sb.AppendLine();
    foreach(Int32[] array in listOfArrays) {
        Boolean isFirst = true;
        foreach(Int32 val in array) {
            if( !isFirst ) sb.Append( ", " );
            sb.Append( val );
            isFirst = false;
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    sb.AppendLine("<br />");
}
da.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want is this:

```
Dictionary< int, List<int> >
```

...a `List<int[]>` doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
clsCollaborativeFilter mri = new clsCollaborativeFilter();
Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> movRecommendations = mri.aList1();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int[]>> kvp in movRecommendations)
{
    da.Text += kvp.Key;
    da.Text += " ";
    da.Text += string.Join(",",kvp.Value);
    da.Text += "<br/>";
}
return da.Text;
```

Comment: Oh true, as Dai posted, you are making dictionary of lists of arrays of ints

Comment: This will still print the signature of the arrays, because `kvp.Value` is a list of `Array`s, what you need instead is to flatten the ints by doing `kvp.Value.SelectMany(i => i)`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that it is Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>, not Dictionary<int, List<int>>.
Well, there are already other answers which will work

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> movRecommendations = new Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>(){
    {0, new List<int[]>(){ new int[]{1, 2, 3} }},
    {1, new List<int[]>(){ new int[]{7, 8, 9} }}
};
string da = String.Empty; 
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int[]>> kvp in movRecommendations)
{
    da += kvp.Key;
    da += " ";
    da += String.Join(", ", kvp.Value.SelectMany(i => i));
    da += "<br/>";
}
Console.WriteLine (da);
```

This will write out `0 1, 2, 3<br/>1 7, 8, 9<br/>`